# Plot3D Marketing Theme Help

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

New to Mathematica so forgive me if this seems trite.

Using the following code

```
RevolutionPlot3D[3 t, {t, 0, 3}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 1, 1], Opacity[0.67]], 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.67]], 
    PlotTheme -> "Marketing", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3}]
```

I get the following result

[image]

The problem is that with this theme, if I orient the graphic such that +x,+y, and +z all point in their standard directions, the half-box is oriented such that my solid is behind it. How could I change the axes such that my image is visible and with axes pointing in the appropriate direction?

Comment: Post your code in a code block so that readers can copy and paste it into a notebook.

Comment: RevolutionPlot3D[3 t, {t, 0, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 1, 1], Opacity[0.67]], 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.67]], PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3}]

Comment: In the meantime I've just turned axes off and am content with the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are confused about what are the x,y,z axes.  If you add `AxesLabel->{x,y,z}`, you'll see that in fact Plot was smart enough to color the "back" three sides.  You've reoriented the output so that the vertical axis is -y, the horizontal axis is z, and the into the page axes is -x, which is why the labels are "reversed".

Based on your comments, I belive what you really want to ask is how to generate a surface of reovlution about the x axes.  The answer to that is to use the RevolutionAxis option, as shown here

```
RevolutionPlot3D[3 t, {t, 0, 3}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 1, 1], Opacity[0.67]], 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.67]],
    PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
    RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}        
]
```

This will generate what I belive to be the output you want, and if you rotated is the x is horizontal and z is vertical, you'll still see the labels you want: 0 to 3 from left to right for x, and -10 to 10 from bottom to top for the z axis.

Comment: This still isn't working when I use RevolutionPlot3D

Comment: @LanierFreeman What version are you using?

Comment: 11.1 version of Mathematica

Comment: I can't reproduce that with 11.1 on either OSX or Linux.  Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by "the standard directions".  I assumed the you meant a vertical z either positive up, horizontal x with postive to thr right, and y into the screen.  That gives a back, left, and bottom screen with the cone pointed upwards in front the backdrop.

Comment: If you refer to my picture, note the vertical axis becomes negative as you go higher. I want that axis to become positive as you go higher

Comment: OK, that's the y axis.  What do you want for z and x?

Comment: X and z are fine, I just want this to appear like a solid of revolution about the x axis with the box at -x,-y, and -z